# Getting c.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angle, angular-datatables

I am using Angle and Datatables. I'm trying to freeze my table's first column, to do that, I have imported the datatables.fixedColumns (if I check on the generated base.js the plugin is there), but I'm still getting the following error:

```
c.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor
```

I am calling the plugin with this:

```
DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withOption('searching', true)
      .withOption('scrollY', "400px")
      .withFixedColumns({leftColumns: 1})
```

Anyone has an idea about what might be happening?

Comment: You ned to include the FixedColumns source files and include the `datatables.fixedcolumns` module as well.

Comment: I have already done that... I'm using angle and thus, I put the following lines in my vendor.json

`"bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedcolumns/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js",`

Then, I have written this in my lazyload.constants.js

`{name: 'datatables.fixedcolumns',   files: ['vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedcolumns/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js']},`

And to finish I've put this in my routes.config when calling the needed url:

`helper.resolveFor('datatables', 'datatables.fixedcolumns')`

What am I missing?